# Element not being created on onclick

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to make one element disapear and another be created on another part of my document. When the item that I want to disapear is clicked it disapears, however the element I want to create isn't created. I have definitly appended it to the correct element so I'm very confused as to why it doesnt appear in chrome dev tools or on the page. Here's the code and thanks for any help.

```
let hideGridItem = document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let hideItem = (e.target.parentElement.parentElement.id)
    let hideItemTwo = (e.target.parentElement.id)
    let hideItemThree = (e.target.id)

    const displayedItemWrapper = document.getElementById('selected-item-container')

    let hiddenItem = document.getElementById(hideItem)
    if(hideItem.includes('grid-item')){
        hiddenItem.style.display = 'none';

        let hiddednItemWeapon = (hiddenItem.childNodes[2].childNodes[0].innerHTML);
        let hiddednItemCondition = (hiddenItem.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML);
        let hiddenItemImg = (hiddenItem.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].src);
        let hiddednItemWeaponName = (hiddenItem.childNodes[2].childNodes[1].innerHTML);
        let hiddednItemWeaponPrice = (hiddenItem.childNodes[2].childNodes[2].innerHTML);

        let displayedItemContainer = document.createElement('div');
        displayedItemContainer.className = 'selected-item-container';

        let displayedItemImgContainer = document.createElement('div');
        displayedItemImgContainer.className = 'selected-item-img-container';

        let displayedItemImg = document.createElement('img');
        displayedItemImg.src = hiddenItemImg;

        displayedItemWrapper.appendChild.displayedItemContainer;
        displayedItemContainer.appendChild.displayedItemImgContainer;
        displayedItemImgContainer.appendChild.displayedItemImgContainer;
    }

    let hiddenItemTwo = document.getElementById(hideItemTwo)
    if(hideItemTwo.includes('grid-item') ){
        hiddenItemTwo.style.display = 'none'
    }

    let hiddenItemThree = document.getElementById(hideItemThree)
    if(hideItemThree.includes('grid-item') ){
        hiddenItemThree.style.display = 'none'
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: `appendChild` is a function so `appendChild.displayedItemContainer` doesn't make much sense. I think you meant to write `appendChild(displayedItemContainer)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've used ```appendChild``` 287 times in this project so I have no clue why I did that. It's always the small obvious things.

Comment: `let hideGridItem = document.addEventListener(...)` <-- This won't work because `addEventListener` returns `None` (i.e. `void`).